# google maps opening in both native and web apps in ios using phonegap

Tags: ios, google-maps, cordova

I want to open the native application for direction in ios if it is installed in the iphone/ipad otherwise web app, but when i am using my code it is opening both native first and then web app if installed. My code is like:

```
setTimeout(function(){
           window.open('http://maps.google.com/maps?   saddr='+clat+','+clong+'&daddr='+lat+','+lng+'&directionsmode=driving','_blank');
          },2000);


window.location='comgooglemaps://?saddr='+window.localStorage.getItem("clat")+','+window.localStorage.getItem("clong")+'&daddr='+lat+','+lng+'&directionsmode=driving';
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use inAppBrowser. It will automatically open the native google map in the device.

`var ref = window.open(encodeURI('your google map url'), '_system', 'location=no');`

Comment: its giving option to select maps application but not opening directly the native map app

Comment: Yes, that how it works. If you have multiple map apps, you can select the app.